# using mapconcat to concatenate a list containing a variable

Tags: elisp, string-concatenation, quoting

I'm trying to join a list of strings using mapconcat, but can't figure out how to include a variable as one of the list elements. Here's what I'm going for:

```
(mapconcat #'identity '("" "path" "to" "someplace") "/")
=> "/path/to/someplace"
```

But when I try to include a variable:

```
(let ((path "someplace"))
  (mapconcat #'identity '("" "path" "to" path) "/"))
=> Wrong type argument: sequencep, path
```

This doesn't work either:

```
(let ((path "someplace"))
  (mapconcat #'(lambda (x) (format "%s" x)) '("" "path" "to" path) "/"))
=> "/path/to/path"
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're quoting the list with `'`, which means that any symbols are included as symbols in the list, instead of being dereferenced as variables.

You can either use the `list` function:

```
(list "" "path" "to" path)
```

or use a backquote and a comma, to force evaluation of one of the list elements:

```
`("" "path" "to" ,path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer - I'm just getting started with elisp, and this is a good distinction to understand.